# how to use chrome API without creating an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to use chrome API without creating an extension. Is it possible?

Comment: This is not possible. Maybe there is a workaround if you describe what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Some limited API's are accessible to webpages in Google Chrome, like some methods of `chrome.runtime` API, but without knowing which API(s) you want to use there is no accurate answer.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko  I want to capture(video record) the screen of the active tab for that maybe I can use chrome api(chrome.tabCapture) but I don't want to create an extension to use this api. 
I have html page where two buttons will be displayed start and stop. when i click start it has to record current tab bypassing defult popup which is share your scrre.

Comment: `chrome.tabCapture` is only available for chrome extensions.